# Selenium (Python) pattern matching

Tags: python, selenium, pattern-matching, conditional-statements, try-except

Currently writing a Python program using Selenium that fills out an online form. Once the form has been filled and submitted, there are 3 possible redirects.

I am trying to write a function that determines which page I am redirected to.

I wrote a function using 3 try-except blocks, but I am having trouble catching the `NoSuchElementException`.

```py
def match():

    try:
         match = driver.find_element_by_id("hi")
         return 'condition 1'
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass

    try:
        match = driver.find_element_by_id("hey")
        return 'condition 2'
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass

    try:
        match = driver.find_element_by_id("hello")
        return 'condition 3'
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass

    return 'none'
```

I am receiving the following exception

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="hi"]

Side note: Does anyone know of a more elegant approach for pattern matching in Python?

Comment: Put the following line at the top: `from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is raised because selenium is looking for the element before the element was event loaded to the page.

A more elegant approach would be to use a `selenium.webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait` which allows you to hold the execution flow until a condition is met (e.g. A presence of an element in the dom)

further reading: [Selenium waits documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Using xpath you can specify multiple elements inside the condition so when one of them is present the condition will be met. [For example, see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45279138/7278305).

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def match():        
    switcher = {
        'hi': 'condition 1',
        'hey': 'condition 2',
        'hello': 'condition 3'
    }

    try:

        # Wait for 10 seconds max until one of the elements is present or give up
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id = 'hi' or @id = 'hey' or @id = 'hello'"))
        )            
        return switcher[element.get_attribute('id')]
    except TimeoutException:
        return None
```